# JQuery set variable with value from page

Tags: jquery, variables, load

How can I insert a value to variable with:

```
$("#TEST").load("GET.php #Message_1");
```

An example of that:

```
var MSG = $("#TEST").load("GET.php #Message_1");

alert(MSG);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value in the callback function:

```
$("#TEST").load("GET.php #Message_1", function() {
    var msg = $(this).text();
    alert(msg);
});
```

Comment: thanks, is work! but how i can use the variable 'msg' out of function ?

Comment: Assign a global variable instead of a local variable. But remember, it won't be available until after the callback executes.

Comment: You can give me example?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#TEST").load("GET.php #Message_1");

var msg = $("#TEST").val();
alert(msg);
```